# HTTP Status Code 403

Tags: web-access, html, parsing, url

I'm working with some scraping and have run into a bit of a problem. The website I am scraping is this: https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/CRM/stocktalks
I am essentially trying to scrape the "stock talks", but that is not the problem. Using the developer tools on my browser, I've noticed that as I scroll down the page and more Tweet like stock talks show up, the URL that initiates them look like this: https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/CRM/more_stocktalks?user_id=47745202&time=3&force_filter_symbol%5B%5D=crm&force_filter_subject_types%5B%5D=StockTalks
The scroll pages are all the same except for one number that goes "&time=". In the URL above it is the third reload page, and it keeps going on and on.

Opening the first 14 of these URLs is no problem, and I simply do this with:

```
Import["https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/CRM/more_stocktalks?user_id=47745202&time=14&force_filter_symbol%5B%5D=crm&force_filter_subject_types%5B%5D=StockTalks","JSON"]
```

That opens up the JSON for the 14th website. But when I start trying to pull the 15th website and URLs beyond that, I get this error:
FetchURL::httperr: The request to URL https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/CRM/more_stocktalks?user_id=47745202&time=20&force_filter_symbol%5B%5D=crm&force_filter_subject_types%5B%5D=StockTalks was not successful. The server returned the HTTP status code 403 ("Forbidden").

I've read somewhere that this might be because you can't have spaces in your urls, but I don't see the difference between the 14th URL and the 15th. Can anyone help?

Comment: It works for me...

Comment: Strange, I tried it in a new notebook and it works, but doesn't when I run it on the same one as pages previous to 15

Comment: I don't know about this particular web site, but some sites actively prevent web scraping by returning errors like 403 FORBIDDEN if too many requests are received within a short time period.

Comment: @WReach, yeah that seems to be what's happening. If I space out the scraper to different time intervals I'm able to retrieve several pages at a time